# What is the syntax for require.config for chartjs-plugin-streaming and dependencies using RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, chart.js, rcloud

I am trying to set RequireJS require.config() for Javascript libraries on the fly.  I am using this configuration for [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) and [Chartjs Streaming Plugin](https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-streaming/):

```
require.config({
        paths: {
    'moment': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min',
    'chart': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart',
    'streaming': '//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-streaming@1.3.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-streaming.min'
        },
        shim: {
           'chart': {
            exports: 'C'
            },
           'streaming': {
                exports: 'C',
                deps: ['moment','chart']
            }
        }
});
```

I am trying to create a [simple line chart](https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-streaming/samples/line-horizontal.html) using this Javascript code:

```
require(['moment', 'chart', 'streaming'], function (moment, C, streaming) {
   var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
   var chrt = new C.Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: { datasets: [{ data: [1,2,3,4,5] },{ data: [-1,0,1,2,3] }] }
    })
})
```

This script creates a simple Chart.js chart if I do **not** include the chartjs-plugin-streaming.min.js code.

[image: Chart.js renders excludes chart streaming plugin require]

However, when I try to add that script using the require.config() above, I see in Chrome that I am getting a 500 Error for "chart.js" even thought Chart.js is already loaded:
[image: Chart.js does not render when including chart streaming plugin]

**My question is, am I requiring the chartjs-plugin-streaming and its dependencies correctly, please?** Or is there another problem?

Comment: Does it work with no `shim` section? The fact it is looking for lowercase `chart.js` makes me think it's your dependencies in the streaming `shim`.

Comment: Thank you, but no, unfortunately, you need to export at least Chart.js as a object...but that shim works - it produces a chart.  Yes, I think my dependencies in 'streaming' not right somehow too, but I based it on what I could understand from the RequireJS documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chartjs-plugin-streaming` is looking for `'chart.js'` as you can see in [index.js in the GitHub source](https://github.com/nagix/chartjs-plugin-streaming/blob/master/src/index.js) and below.

```
'use strict';

import Chart from 'chart.js';
import moment from 'moment';

import realTimeScale from './scales/scale.realtime';
import streamingPlugin from './plugins/plugin.streaming';

realTimeScale(Chart, moment);

var plugin = streamingPlugin(Chart);
Chart.plugins.register(plugin);
export default plugin;
```

Because it has the `'.js'` extension in the name for the `import`, you have to export something in your `require.config` with that name.

You need a RequireJS `map` so `chartjs-plugin-streaming` can find that file. Here's the fixed `require.config`.

```js
require.config({
  paths: {
    moment: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min",
    chart: "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min",
    streaming: "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-streaming@1.3.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-streaming.min"
  },
  shim: {
    chartjs: {
      exports: "C"
    },
    streaming: {
      exports: "C",
      deps: ["moment", "chart"]
    }
  },
  map: {
    streaming: {
      "chart.js": "chart"
    }
  }
});

require(["moment", "chart", "streaming"], function(moment, chart) {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
  var chrt = new chart.Chart(ctx, {
    type: "line",
    data: { datasets: [{ data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }, { data: [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3] }] }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.5/require.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is and old post, but I just managed to solve this by changing the define reference on the chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js, version 0.7.0  from define(["charts.js"]) to define(["path of my file"])

From (first two lines):

```
!function(t,e){"object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module?module.exports=e(require("chart.js")):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["charts.js"],e) ...
```

to:

```
!function(t,e){"object"==typeof exports&&"undefined"!=typeof module?module.exports=e(require("chart.js")):"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["../charts/Chart.min.js"],e ...
```